# What is the purpose of double and triple underscore _ in iPython?

Tags: ipython

As I understand, standalone `_` merely retrieves the last console output, double underscore `__` the output before that and triple underscore `___` gets output third from the last. This is an interesting, however seemingly useless feature from the first glance...

I use `_` as a variable placeholder when I don't need a name, but is there any other use of `_`, along with `__` and `___`? And, why there is no quadruple-underscore or more?

This only works for iPython, ordinary python 2.7 interpreter shows error for anything but single underscore.

Comment: Well, in addition to retrieve variables there some conventions around the underscore use, maybe you want to have a look at https://hackernoon.com/understanding-the-underscore-of-python-309d1a029edc. Here, such conventions are explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> standalone _ merely retrieves the last console output

Not the "console output", but the actual resulting value, i.e. the object itself:

```
>>> object()
<object object at 0x1002b10a0>
>>> _
<object object at 0x1002b10a0>
```

> is there any other use of _?

by convention `_` is used as a name the value of which is ignored (you might prefer the name `dummy` though).  This is only a convention though.

> ... along with __ and *_*?

No. No other use for `__` and `___`.

> why there is no quadruple-underscore or more?

There just isn't. *You* claimed it's a useless feature, so why would you want more of it?

(I tried answering all the explicit questions in your post, though I have to admit I'm not sure what you're getting at...)

Comment: Someone has coded it into the interpreter, I'm asking why because I don't know. For me it is useless, someone else thought it's a good idea if it is there.

Comment: It isn't coded into the "core" of the language. It is coded into the interactive shell(s) of the langauge, including `ipython`. Some people, myself included, find `_` useful. Others, myself not included, also find `__` and `___` useful. I think that's a sufficient reason for including this simple feature.